# File reading error

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io, process, exe

I've two methods. One is for image comparison and one is for file reading. what i do is I call a process that compares images between two folders and creates a logfile. Now the second method reads that logfile and parse the data. 
But when i call the second method, it says, file not exist, this is because the exe take a little time to make the logfile.
I have used Thread.Sleep() but it still don't work, neither i can use that file.exist method as if i use it and if file does not exist then it will skip that method/file which i don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) to wait until your first process is finished, then you know when your log file will be complete/exist when calling your second method.

Comment: No worries, if this answered your question you should check the tick to show it as accepted.